# embedded function using ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm having trouble executing my program due to the following error message:
`undefined reference to 'typeOfTriangle(int*, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'`

```
void classify(int sides[], ofstream &outfile)
{

  int largest(int []);
  void typeOfTriangle(int [], ofstream &);
  bool isRightTriangle(int []);

  outfile << "Largest Sides: " << largest(sides) << endl;
  typeOfTriangle(sides,outfile);

  if(isRightTriangle(sides))
      outfile << "Right Triangle\n";
  else
      outfile << "Not a right triangle\n";
}
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of typeOfTriangle?

Comment: Sounds like `typeOfTriangle` is defined in another source file (if it is defined at all).

Comment: "executing" or maybe compiling?

Comment: Why are you forward declaring functions ( not sure if that is your intention ) in side another function ? Usual forward declarations are made at global scope. Also, if the function definition is provide in another source file, did you compile and link it ?

Comment: @Borgleader http://ideone.com/ZKETGC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void typeOfTriange(int sides[], ofstream &outfile)
{
    //..
}
```

According to your comment [this](http://ideone.com/ZKETGC) is your definition for the function which doesnt match your forward declaration. You forgot an l in Triangle.

Comment: We all do that from time to time ;)

Answer (score 1):

it's a linker error, either you have not defined typeOfTriangle, or you have not linked all of your object files.